# Calculate distance between two coordinates for a fixed point in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopy

I have the following DataFrame in pandas:

| code | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 40.410323 | -3.993046 |
| 02 | 41.490604 | 1.696572 |
| 03 | 39.287817 | -0.435448 |
| 04 | 38.594316 | -0.128489 |
| 05 | 36.900799 | -3.423063 |
| 06 | 36.541667 | -4.625 |

I want to create a new column called `km_to_fixed_coords` in which the distance in coordinates to a new fixed point is calculated, which will be the same for all rows `(36.7196, -4.42002)`.

This code calculates the distance between two coordinates in kilometres.

```
import geopy.distance
# (latitude, longitude)
coords_1 = (x, y)
fixed_coords = (36.7196, -4.42002)

print(geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, fixed_coords).km)
```

The resulting DataFrame should look like the example:

| code | latitude | longitude | km_to_fixed_coords |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 40.410323 | -3.993046 | 411.3819700981563 |
| 02 | 41.490604 | 1.696572 | 748.2482442578678 |
| 03 | 39.287817 | -0.435448 | 451.2806740048897 |
| 04 | 38.594316 | -0.128489 | 432.0145327165797 |
| 05 | 36.900799 | -3.423063 | 91.20470627900332 |
| 06 | 36.541667 | -4.625342 | 26.96511660526825 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from typing import Tuple
import geopy.distance


def distance(
    lat: float, lon: float, fixed_coords: Tuple[float] = (36.7196, -4.42002)
) -> float:
    return geopy.distance.distance((lat, lon), fixed_coords).km


df["km_to_fixed_coords"] = df.apply(lambda row: distance(row.latitude, row.longitude))
```

Answer (score 0):

apply a method on rows like this ?

```py
import geopy.distance

# (latitude, longitude)
fixed_coords = (36.7196, -4.42002)

df['km_to_fixed_coords'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: geopy.distance.distance((row.latitude, row.longitude), fixed_coords).km,
    axis=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

#Current Location (longitude , latitude )
current_coord = Point(-3.993046, 40.410323 )
#Target Location (longitude , latitude )
target_coord =  Point(1.696572, 41.490604 )
#Calculate distance in kilometer 
distance = current_coord.distance(target_coord) * 100