# Attribute error while running apply function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use this technique [Calculate distance between two coordinates for a fixed point in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72965047/calculate-distance-between-two-coordinates-for-a-fixed-point-in-a-dataframe)

```
   from typing import Tuple
import geopy.distance


def distance(
    lat: float, lon: float, fixed_coords: Tuple[float] = (36.7196, -4.42002)
) -> float:
    return geopy.distance.distance((lat, lon), fixed_coords).km


x = dataframe.apply(lambda row: distance(row[lat], row[lon],axis =1))
```

error:

```
---> 11 x = dataframe.apply(lambda row: distance(row[lat], row[lon],axis =1))

NameError: name 'lat' is not defined
```

Comment: my data set contains "lat" and "lon" as columns.

Comment: If those are the literal column names then why aren't you passing them as strings? Like `row["lat"], row["lon"]`?

Comment: Yes, but lat and lon need to be in quotes:  `distance(row['lat'], row['lon'], axis=1)`

Comment: KeyError: 'lat' when using distance(row['lat'], row['lon'], axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

The [name error](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-nameerror-exception-in-python/) is becasue the interpreter thinks `lat` and `lon` are variable names, not the name of columns. Try using strings instead.

```
x = dataframe.apply(lambda row: distance(row["lat"], row["lon"],axis =1))
```

Comment: KeyError: 'lat'

Comment: What is the datatype of row? Are you sure that "lat" and "lon" are present in row?

Comment: they are column names in the dataframe containing longitude and latitude data as int64

Comment: If you are getting a `KeyError` that means "lat" and "lon" are not keys in the dataframe. You should verify all of the column names are what you expect, I recommend using something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188960/how-to-show-all-columns-names-on-a-large-pandas-dataframe